# Object displacement in BGE

Tags: game-engine, displacement

I have an object created in Cycles. After switching to BGE some parts(bandwrist elements) are significantly changing its position, though in viewport everything is correctly displayed. 
In other threads it is said that problem can be related to broken modifiers, but in this file I've found modifiers that only affect shape of bandwrist elements and after disabling them, displacement still being there anyways.

Blend file : http://www.filedropper.com/wristwatch

[image: BGE render result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually just remove parenting of every object.